# Apply multiple custom functions to groupby objects and print output

Tags: python, pandas, function, group-by

I have written a set of custom functions aimed to print calculations derived from a dataframe, however I want to fulfill this same aim but on subsets of the dataframe defined by a column groupby. Ideally I would iterate through each groupby object, print the key, pass the values to the functions and print results one by one.

Here's example data:

```
df.head()

    client  reg_goal    paid_regs   spend       
0   a       50.0        45.0        955.0   
1   b       700.0       550.0       1045.2  
2   c       130.0       135.0       630.0   
3   d       70.0        0.0         35.0    
4   e       1000.0      817.0       27240.0
```

Here's desired output example:

```
a 

client a acquired 45 regs, which is 90% of the reg goal. 

b

client a acquired 550 regs, which is 79% of the reg goal.
```

and so on...

Here is an example of a custom function:

```
def reg_performance(data):
    paid_regs = data['paid_regs'].values
    paid_regs_sum = np.sum(paid_regs)
    reg_goal = data['reg_goal'].values
    reg_goal_sum = np.sum(reg_goal)
    reg_pct = round(100*(paid_regs_sum/reg_goal_sum), 2)
    reg_stats = paid_regs, paid_regs_sum, reg_goal, reg_goal_sum, reg_pct
    return reg_stats
```

Here is my attempted code to iterate through groupby objects and test atleast one custom function by instantiating a function object while passing the sub-dataframe as a parameter.

```
client_grouped = df.groupby('client')
groups = dict(list(client_grouped))

for k, v in groups.items(): 
    print(k)
    reg_performance = reg_performance(v)
```

Logic is that any of these custom functions takes a dataframe as a parameter, so passing iterator objects in the form of subdata shouldn't be a problem, but I keep hitting `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

Does anybody know how to resolve this TypeError?

Comment: Problem seems to be you're overwriting the name of your function with `reg_performance = reg_performance(v)`, so second time you try to call it, it's no longer a function but the return of the previous call, which is a tuple...

Comment: @filbranden any suggestions